# Typescript interfaces

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I am trying to create an interface for the following object in angular 2:

```
// set the render state object
    this.aRenderState = {
      model: "",
      colour: false,
      showWireframe: false,
      showGrid: true,
      clipping: {
          enabled: false,
          visible: false,
          planes: [
              {
                  name: 'X',
                  plane: new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), 0),
                  object: null,
                  enabled: true,
                  flip: false,
                  size: [this.aDomain.getSize().z, this.aDomain.getSize().y],
              },
              {
                  name: 'Y',
                  plane: new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0),
                  object: null,
                  enabled: false,
                  flip: false,
                  size: [this.aDomain.getSize().x, this.aDomain.getSize().z]
              },
              {
                  name: 'Z',
                  plane: new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1), 0),
                  object: null,
                  enabled: false,
                  flip: false,
                  size: [this.aDomain.getSize().x, this.aDomain.getSize().y]
              },
          ]
      }
    }
```

the following is my attempt:

```
export interface IPlane {
  name: string;
  plane: THREE.Plane;
  object: {};
  enabled: boolean;
  flip: boolean;
  size: number[];
}

export interface IClipping {
  enabled: boolean;
  visible: boolean;
  planes: IPlane[];
}

export interface IRenderState {
  model: string;
  colour: boolean;
  showWireframe: boolean;
  showGrid: boolean;
  clipping: IClipping;
}
```

when i run the project I get the following error message:

> Type '{ model: string; colour: false; showWireframe: false; showGrid:
>   true; clipping: { enabled: false;...' is not assignable to type
>   'IRenderState'.   Types of property 'clipping' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ enabled: false; visible: false; planes: [{ name: string; plane: Plane; object: null; enabled: t...' is not assignable to type
>   '{ enabled: boolean; visible: boolean; planes: [IPlane, IPlane,
>   IPlane]; }'.
>         Types of property 'planes' are incompatible.
>           Type '[{ name: string; plane: Plane; object: null; enabled: true; flip: false; size: [number, number]; ...' is not assignable to
>   type '[IPlane, IPlane, IPlane]'.
>             Type '{ name: string; plane: Plane; object: null; enabled: true; flip: false; size: [number, number]; }' is not assignable to
>   type 'IPlane'.
>               Types of property 'size' are incompatible.
>                 Type '[number, number]' is not assignable to type '[0, 0]'.
>                   Type 'number' is not assignable to type '0'.)

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In your IPlane interface, object:object rather than object:{}

Comment: Dear John, thank you for your answer but the object: object; declaration gives the error cannot find the name object.

Comment: OK John, all it needed was to declare **object:Object** capital O. If you put your comment into a proper answer I am happy to accept your solution and upvote it. Again, thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Dino the `object` type was introduced in TypeScript 2.2, so you will need to upgrade to use it. Worth noting that `Object` and `object` are different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript 2.2 Has "object" type (all lower). It is recommended to use this one from now.

```
interface IPlane {
    object: object;
}
```